# LGSVL invalid simulation

Tags: ros2

I was able to run the simulator last week, but now I get the fallowing errors

> Invalid: Unsupported message type Simulator.Bridge.Data.ClockData used for ROS bridge
> Invalid: No ROS RMW set. You need to set RMW_IMPLEMENTATION to rmw_cyclonedds_cpp

every time I reenter and update ade docker, the error changes.
A colleague of mine is getting the same and we couldn't have done the same mistakes.[Simulation error when run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVDdB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, apparently they changed the sensors to run on ROS2 instead of ROS...
I just had to change the vehicle, sensor parameters.